What is the best way of recognising digits in the real world?
I have spent a long time implementing a neural network from scratch (as a learning exercise). I have managed to get good results training on MNIST (over 98% on the test data).
Like many others, I have tried to apply my model to new user drawn digits but I am really struggling to get good results (accuracy < 50%).
Things which I have done:

I am taking a 8 bit greyscale image which is 280 x 280 pixels and
scaling down to 28 x 28 pixels. I am using Qt's scaled function for
this and apply the smooth transformation.

I change the image so that it matches the MNIST format (black
background i.e. 0)

I then convert into a vector (row by row).

I apply log normalisation to the vector which is the same
normalisation I applied when training on MNIST.


The MNIST image and user drawn images look relatively similar.
Is there something which I am missing here - some pre-processing step I should be taking? Or is the MNIST sample just not representative enough? If the latter, is there a better dataset to use (what do commercial OCR companies use)?
Thanks
